# Add VBA code to date picker to control allowed dates

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker

I am using the following formula to embed a date picker in my cell.

```
=EMBED("LDDATETIME.LDDateCtrl.1","")
```

My question is how can I control the dates that a user can select. For instance I don't want them to be able to select any future dates only past dates.

I have tried this but it gives me an object undefined error:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If LDDate1 > Date Then
MsgBox "Error"
End If
End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to track the change in Worksheet... Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Value > Date And Target.Column = 3 Then 'The Second part Target.Column assumes that you have the Dates that are being changes in the second column
    MsgBox "Error"
  End If
End Sub
```